# Gem Server and Rails RDoc Not Found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rdoc

I would like to read Rails documentation locally though gem server.

I go to

```
http://localhost:8808/
```

and Rails 2.3.3 gem is in the list of the gems installed, but when I click [rdoc] I get:

```
`/doc_root/rails-2.3.3/rdoc/index.html' not found.
```

I tried to uninstall and reinstall Rails but I got no effect.

All other gems work properly, why I can't see Rails documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails itself has no documentation while you can read rdocs about actionmailer, actionpack, activerecord, activeresource or activesupport.

Comment: sorry my bad, I assumed that it does not default with rdoc and ri, +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to explicitly generate ri and rdoc during gem installation.  The command is as follows:

```
$ sudo gem install rails --rdoc --ri
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

http://railsapi.com/

Just download this to your gem docs dir.